# Watching Variables in Eclipse without breakpoint

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm developing a Java timer application and would like to monitor the value of a variable but as it is changing regularly and slowly I don't necessarily need to have a breakpoint. So would like to add a Watch to a variable but don't want a breakpoint, is this possible?

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could log the variable to a file.  Then you could monitor that file with a tail type program, eg WinTail for windows or tail for 'nix systems.

Comment: that would work better as an answer without the question mark.

Comment: Indeed - I've been told before that it's rude to answer a question with a question, but I never learn ;)

Comment: Thanks,currently logging to Console. Will look into logging to file, hadn't thought of that

Comment: @Matt -- not really rude; depending on wording + how someone interprets it, it can either sound like you're unsure or being snarky. Anyway good simple solution.

Comment: @Jason - Thanks - I was mostly being flippant with my last comment - except I have been told that in the past. It's too big a generalisation to be actually true though.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your best option might be to output the value of the variable whenever it is changed.